# Android Runtime error:Package couldn't be installed

Tags: android

i am developing an ANDROID app (PENDROID app (5 apps in 1 app(like music player, note pad, paint etc... in 1 app))) while running the application my LOG cat shows 2 warnings and console shows "launching cancelled"

1. W/PackageManager(59): Can't install because provider name com.google.provider.NotePad (in package com.badlogic.androidgames.framework) is already used by com.example.android.notepad
2. W/PackageManager(59): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.badlogic.androidgames.framework-1.apk

plz help me to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall notepad first

In console
`adb uninstall com.example.android.notepad`

Comment: thanks..i have another notpad app in ecplise may b becoz f that?? ryt?? bt what about 2nd warning??

Comment: The second warning is a result of the first. Your application is declcaring a provider (search provider I believe in the example) with the same name which causes a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your package name which consists of your notepad app